# Debug.WriteLine and its Character encoding

Tags: c#

Why is the output different between Console and Debug?

```
byte [] data = new byte [] {0xB1, 0x00,0xA6,0x7C, 0x4e, 0xEC, 0xE7, 0xFF, 0xDD, 0xCE};

Console.WriteLine (new String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetChars(data)));
Console.WriteLine (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));

Debug.WriteLine (new String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetChars(data)));
Debug.WriteLine (new String(Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(data)));
```

"Console.WriteLine" (Latin1 encoding) output -> ±¦|NìçÿÝÎ

"Console.WriteLine" (UTF8) output -> ��|N�����

"Debug.WriteLine" shows no output.

Comment: Are you asking why the encodings are different, or why the visible output is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `0x00` in the second position of the array, which is, as you know, a string end. `Debug.WriteLine` outputs in the ASCII encoding. Therefore, it outputs only the first byte in the Output window.

If you change `0x00` to `0x01` you will see the full output.

**MORE** When I look at `new String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetChars(data))` in the Watch window I see an exception being thrown:

`'new String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetChars(data))' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'  string {System.ArgumentException}`

This usually happens when attempting to access an Array element that doesn't exist.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: My problem turned out to be the 0x00 in my array. I should have caught that from the beginning, not three hours later. What sent me in the wrong direction was that the VS output window and console window for some reason display different results.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly garbage-in-garbage-out.

The � character is the [Unicode replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replacement_character#Replacement_character), code U+FFFD.  You get a lot of them  because the byte values do no contain proper utf-8 encoding values.

The Debug.Print() statement *does* produced output, at least on my machine.  Look in the Output window.  You'll just see the first character of the string because the default listener for debug output is a function that calls the Windows OutputDebugString() api function.  Which sends output to the debugger.  This is a C language based api function, the 0 is a string terminator so it will only ever print a single character.

Whatever you are trying to do, it is pretty clear that the byte values do *not* represent text.  I don't see any kind of pattern to have a guess at what the binary data might be.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Because it calls into [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is ASCII by default for compatibility reasons.
I do not know of a workaround off the top of my head, but I will look for one.</del>

**EDIT**

Actually, I cannot reproduce your issue.  On my machine I get this output:

> ±□¦|NìçÿÝÎ
>
> �□�|N�����
>
> ±□¦|NìçÿÝÎ
>
> �□�|N�����